# How can I merge, split and query k-th of sorted lists?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

Initially I have n elements, they are in n tiles.

I need to support 3 kinds of queries:

1. merge two tiles into one tile.
2. split one tile into two tiles. (Formally for a tile of size k, split it into two tiles of size k1 and k2, k=k1+k2, the first tile contains the smallest k1 elements and the second tile contains the rest)
3. find the k-th smallest element in one tile.

Still assuming there are n queries. What worst-case time complexity can I achieve?

Comment: 1. O(n1 + n2), 2. Depending on the data structure any from O(k1 + k2), O(min(k1, k2)), O(1), 3. O(1) with an appropriate data structure. What exactly is your question? These are all very common problems and not too hard to solve.

Comment: :) Obviously I'm asking for a complexity such as O(logn) or O(sqrt(n)). And these queries should be solved all in one... They're not separate problems.

Comment: No, it is not so clear what you are asking. Are you looking for amortized time complexity for any number of merge and split operations? What do you mean by solve all at one?

Comment: How are you doing merging. I mean is it like if you have a list of tiles then you are only supposed to merge 2 consecutive tiles ??

Comment: Nope, I may merge any two tiles. @Shasha99

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Strictly taken, the answer to the question *What time complexity can I achieve?* is O(1). This is the case when all queries are of type 3.

Comment: Ok, And elements in a tile will always be sorted ?

Comment: You may not sort it. But split and find k-th is based on sorting. @Shasha99

Comment: The worst case is obviously alternating split and merge when all elements are initially in a single tile and all other tiles are empty. Based on the answer of Ami, this gives you a time complexity of O(n log n) for tree-based data structures and O(n^2) for list-based structures.

Comment: There was something wrong with Ami's solution, but I think O(nlogn) is achieveable. Can you share your ideas?

Comment: I can share O(n) solution. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I would be really greatful, if you mean O(n) in total for all n queries... plz post your approach.

Comment: @newbie For all queries, it would be n.sqrt(n) in total.

Answer (score 1):

*That will not be a complete answer*, but some thoughts on what can be done.

My idea is based on [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).

Let every tile be an indexable sorted skip list.

**Splitting** then rather simple: find `k-th` element and break every link between `i > k1-th` and `j <= k1-th` elements (there are at most `O(log n)` such links).

**Merging** is trickier.

First, assume that we can **concatenate** two skiplists in `O(log n)`.

Lets say we are merging two tiles `T1` and `T2`.

- Compare the first elements `t1` from `T1` and `t2` from `T2`. Let's
  say `t1 < t2`
- Then, find the last `t1'` still less than `t2` in `T1`.
- We must insert `t2` right after `t1'`. But first, we are looking at the element `t1*` right after `t1'` in `T1`.
- Now search for the last `t2'` still less than `t1*` in `T2`.
- An entire sequence of elements from `T2`, starting at `t2` and ending at `t2'`, must be inserted between `t1'` and `t1*`.
- So, we are doing **split** at `t1'` and `t2'`, obtaining new lists `T1a`, `T1b`, `T2a`, `T2b`.
- We concatenating `T1a`, `T2a` and `T1b`, obtaining the new list `T1*`.
- We are repeating the entire process for the `T1*` and `T2b`.

  [image: Algorithm illustration]

In some pseudo-python-code:

```
#skiplist interface:
# split(list, k) - splits list after the k-th element, returns two lists
# concat(list1, list2) - concatenates two lists, returns the new one
# index(list, k) - returns k-th element from the list
# upper_bound(list, val) - returns the index of the last element less that val
# empty(list) - check if list is empty

def Query(tile, k)
    return index(tile, k)

def Split(tile, k)
    return split(tile, k)

def Merge(tile1, tile2):
    if empty(tile1):
        return tile2
    if empty(tile2):
        return tile1

    t1 = index(tile1, 0)
    t2 = index(tile2, 0)

    if t1 < t2:
        #(1)
        i1 = upper_bound(tile1, t2)
        t1s = index(tile1, i1 + 1)
        i2 = upper_bound(tile2, t1s)

        t1_head, t1_tail = split(tile1, i1)
        t2_head, t2_tail = split(tile2, i2)

        head = concat(t1_head, t2_head)
        tail = Merge(t1_tail, t2_tail)

        return concat(head, tail)
    else:
        #swap tile1, tile2, do (1)
```

There are at most `O(p)` such iterations, where `p` is the number of interleaved runs in `T1` and `T2`. Every iteration takes `O(log n)` operations to complete.

As it was noted by @newbie, there is an example where the sum of `p`s equals to `n log n`.
This python script generates such an example for `k = log_2 n` (plus sign in the output stands for merge):

```
def f(l):
    if len(l) == 2:
        return "%s+%s" % (l[0], l[1])
    if len(l) == 1:
        return str(l[0])
    l1 = [l[i] for i in xrange(0, len(l), 2)]
    l2 = [l[i + 1] for i in xrange(0, len(l), 2)]
    l_str = f(l1)
    r_str = f(l2)
    return "(%s)+(%s)" % (l_str, r_str)

def example(k):
    print f(list(range(0, 2 ** k)))
```

For `n = 16`:

```
example(4)
```

Gives us the following queries:

```
(
    (
        (0+8)+(4+12)
    )
    +
    (
        (2+10)+(6+14)
    )
)
+
(
    (
        (1+9)+(5+13)
    )
    +
    (
        (3+11)+(7+15)
    )
)
```

Which is a binary tree where we are merging `2^(k-j)` number of `2^j`-sized tiles in the height `j`. Tiles are constructed in such a way that their elements are always interleaved, so for the tiles of size `q` we are doing `O(q)` splits-concatenations.

However, it still doesn't worsen the overall complexity of `O(n log n)` for this specific case, as (highly informally speaking) each split-concatenation of the 'small' lists costs less than `O(log n)` and there are much more 'small' lists than 'big'.

I'm not sure if there are worse counterexamples, but for now I think the overall worst case complexity for `n` queries is somewhere between `n log^2 n` and `n log n`.

Comment: I have a belief that p is O(nlogn). Let n=2^k, consider {a1...an}={1...n}, let first n/2 elements of a be {1,3,5,...,n-1}, last n/2 be {2,4,6,8,...,n} and construct each half recursively. Then let's merge from bottom to top like doing in a segment tree. Then p will be O(nlogn).

Comment: @newbie, if I understand you correctly, that's probably right. Still, overall complexity of `O(n log^2 n)` isn't that bad. Although we are merging `2 ^ (k - j)` lists of the size `2 ^ j`, not of the size `n`, for every `j < k`, so it is still `O(n log n)` in total. I give it some more thoughts, then will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look for:

1. std::merge or std::set_union
2. std::partition
3. std::find (or std::find_if)

Linear complexity for 1 and 2.
Depends on your container for 3, linear at worst.

But it's not clear what you're asking exactly. Do you have some code we can look at ?

Comment: I'm not interested in linear complexity for an operation.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was a C++ question. It's more about algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

*By the time I asked this question I don't know how to solve it, since it seems that it's okay to answer my own question, I gonna answer this question myself :/*

First, let's suppose the values in the sorted lists are integers between 1~n. If not, you may just sort and map them.

Let's build a segment tree for every sorted list, segment trees are built based on values (1~n). In every node of a segment tree stores how many numbers are in this range, let's call this the value of a node.

It seems that it requires O(nlogn) space to store every segment tree, but we can simply drop the nodes that value=0, and really allocate these nodes only when their value become >0.

So for a sorted list with only one element, we simply build a chain of this value, so only O(logn) memory is needed.

```
int s[SZ]/*value of a node*/,
ch[SZ][2]/*a node's two children*/;
//make a seg with only node p, return in the first argument
//call with sth. like build(root,1,n,value);
void build(int& x,int l,int r,int p)
{
    x=/*a new node*/; s[x]=1;
    if(l==r) return;
    int m=(l+r)>>1;
    if(p<=m) build(ch[x][0],l,m,p);
    else build(ch[x][1],m+1,r,p);
}
```

When we split a segment tree (sorted list), simply split two children recursively:

```
//make a new node t2, split t1 to t1 and t2 so that s[t1]=k
void split(int t1,int& t2,int k)
{
    t2=/*a new node*/;
    int ls=s[ch[t1][0]]; //size of t1's left child
    if(k>ls) split(ch[t1][1],ch[t2][1],k-ls); //split the right child of t1
    else swap(ch[t1][1],ch[t2][1]); //all right child belong to t2
    if(k<ls) split(ch[t1][0],ch[t2][0],k); //split the left child of t1
    s[t2]=s[t1]-k; s[t1]=k;
}
```

When we merge two sorted lists, merge them forcely:

```
//merge trees t1&t2, return merged segment tree
int merge(int t1,int t2)
{
    if(t1&&t2);else return t1^t2; //nothing to merge
    ch[t1][0]=merge(ch[t1][0],ch[t2][0]);
    ch[t1][1]=merge(ch[t1][1],ch[t2][1]);
    s[t1]+=s[t2]; /*erase t2, it's useless now*/ return t1;
}
```

It looks very simple, isn't it? But its total complexity is in fact O(nlogn).

> Proof:
>
> Let's investigate the total number of allocated segment tree nodes.
>
> Initially we will allocate O(nlogn) such nodes (O(logn) for each).
>
> For every spliting attempt we will allocate at most O(logn) more, so it will also be O(nlogn) in total. The reason is obviously we will recursively split only either left child or right child of a node.
>
> So the total number of allocated segment tree nodes will at most be only O(nlogn).
>
> Let's consider merging, except for 'nothing to merge', every time we call merge, the total number of allocated segment tree nodes will decrease by 1 (t2 isn't useful anymore). Obviously 'nothing to merge' will only be called when its father is really merged, so they will have nothing to do with complexity.
>
> the total number of allocated segment tree nodes is O(nlogn), for every useful merge it will decrease 1, so the total complexity of all merges is O(nlogn).
>
> Summing up, and we've got the result.

Querying k-th is also very simple, and we've done :)

```
//query k-th of segment tree x[l,r]
int ask(int x,int l,int r,int k)
{
    if(l==r) return l;
    int ls=s[ch[x][0]]; //how many nodes in left child
    int m=(l+r)>>1;
    if(k>ls) return ask(ch[x][1],m+1,r,k-ls);
    return ask(ch[x][0],l,m,k);
}
```